# No edit button on Area 51 communities

Tags: feature-request, bug, area-51, communities-list

On Stack Overflow:

[image: pic1]

On Area 51:

[image: pic2]

Why is there no edit communities button in Area 51?

That should be added.

Comment: Anna's comment on the answer confirms this is the same root cause, hence duplicate.